# Angular homepage not showing up

Tags: angularjs

My homepage is not instantiated, It's not showing up?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="pollApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="/angular/app.js"></script>

    <title>Poll</title>

</head>
<body>

<div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Routes file:

```
(function () {

    var pollApp = angular.module('pollApp');

    pollApp.config([
        '$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                    templateUrl: '/angular/views/index.html',
                    controller: 'homeController',
                    controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        }
    ]);
})();
```

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    angular.module('pollApp', ['ngRoute']);
})();
```

**Folder structure:**

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

--EDIT--

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'pollApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=pollApp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to add a `<script>` element to load your routes.js file.

You also haven't defined any controller named 'homeController'.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot, but now I receive another error. Please see my edit.

Comment: It must be included **after** app.js, which defines the pollApp module that routes.js needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try on your app.js having this

```
(function () {
    angular.module('pollApp', ['ngRoute']);
})();
```

and in your route.js

```
(function () {

    angular.module('pollApp');
    .config([
        '$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/angular/views/index.html',
                controller: 'homeController',
                controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
        }
    ]);
});
```

Regards